# book recommendations for martingale theory (studying measure theory)

Tags: martingales

Any recommendations for someone studying martingale theory. My course recommends Probability with martingales - David Williams and Probability-2 Albert N. Shiryaev but I've found both to be very dry, with little to no examples or questions. I'm also studying measure theory so any books that mix the two would be great.